# JS event handler execution order on different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

HTML:

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="click me"></input>
<input class="input" type="text"></input>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(){console.log("clicked");})
$(".input").on("blur", function(){console.log("blur");})
```

When I click on the input field and then click on the button, two events have been fired. My question is what order are these two events being fired. Why the `blur` message is always printed before `clicked`? Is there any related document or information on that execution order?

Comment: logically the input must lose focus (blur) before the button is clicked

Comment: Before it can focus on another element, it must lose it's focus on the current element, that's why

Comment: I am quite confused as it seems also logically to me that the input lose focus at the SAME time when the button is clicked

Comment: But things can't really happen at the same time, everything is ordered. The HTML specification goes into detail about the order of events.